# How to return vertically aligned text (python3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am a very beginner for programing.
I'm creating code which return vertically aligned text that exclude non-alphanumeric. And it should be also changed lines by space like

```
H W
e o
l r
l l
o d
```

My code is here.
I could display text vertically.
But this function doesn't return.
So how could I edit this to return vertically text??
It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain the detail.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def transposition(string):
  new_text = str()
  for i in string:
    x = i.isalpha()

    if x == False:
        i = ' '

    new_text += i

for y in zip_longest(*new_text.split(), fillvalue=' '):
    print (' '.join(y))

transposition("Hello, World")
```

Comment: It should be changed line by space.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want a function that takes a string such as `"hello world"` and returns a string such as `"h w\ne o\nl r\n"` etc.

If so I think you are essentially there:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import re

def transposition(string):

    clean_str = re.sub('[^\w]', ' ', string)
    return '\n'.join(
        ' '.join(row)
        for row in zip_longest(*clean_str.split(), fillvalue=' '))

print(transposition("Hello, World... how are you?"))

>> H W h a y
>> e o o r o
>> l r w e u
>> l l   
>> o d
```

Notes:

- I would get in the habit of using regular expressions for any string manipulations.
- You should never compare to `True` or `False`, just do `if x:` or `if not x:`.
- The `' '.join(row) for row in ...` is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) which you can pass to any function that takes an iterable.

Comment: Oh awesome. I didn't know such a way to use return. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: @user7421972 you are welcome, don't forget to accept an answer if one worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
def transposition(string):
  new_text = str()
  for i in string:
    x = i.isalpha()

    if x == False:
        i = ' '

    new_text += i

  for y in new_text:
    print ('\n'.join(y))

transposition("Hello, World")
```

Comment: Case of "Hello, world" I want to display with two lines which is separated after Hello. So I could display it, but I want to use return. Sorry for my very poor English...